# Filter dates December text format D Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of dates that I want to convert to the following format below:

```
Oct 1,5,10,12,18,19,26,27,28,29,30
Nov 2,3,4,9,17,18
Dec 3,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30
Jan 1,2,3,4,5,6,16,18,19,26
Feb 2,9
Mar 2,8,9,10,23
Apr 13,19,20,21,22,27
```

I'm using e.g.

```
=join(",",(filter(text($H$38:$H$204,"d"),month($H$38:$H$204)=10)))
```

where `$H$38:$H$204` refers to the dates to produce the days for October and other months which all work fine with the exception of December (12) which produces repetitive 30 at the end.

It's bizarre behaviour and I can't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it thanks.

if the array has blank cells at the end it seems to produce this behaviour.

Use:

=join(",",(filter(text($H$38:$H$204,"d"),$H$38:$H$204<>"",month($H$38:$H$204)=12))) to filter out blank cells also.

Still bizarre it seems to happen for only one month.

Regards